# Android Studio: modification of a sourcefile propagates through multiple copies

Tags: android

Android Studio 1.0 and 1.1, running on Windows 8.1 and 10:
I developed a sample following book chapters. At the end of each chapter I use FileExplorer copy and paste of the whole project folder to create a copy of the current state. The new folder is then renamed.
When I edited a menu layout file in Android Studio in an older copy of the Android Studio, all of a sudden the change appeared in almost all newer copies of the same file, except the newest one.
Simliar effects happened to my collegues on multiple machines running German and English versions of Windows 8.1 and 10.
What happened and why and how can I avoid this? Thank you very much.